# MS Access sub form not showing all results

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms, ms-access-reports

I have form in which there is sub-form. Sub-form displays data on the basis of one of the value in main form. Currently sub-form displays data for some records and for others it is not showing. When i remove condition, value are displayed and i can see master value and child value are same. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

below is the form:
[image]

Comment: We don't have your data, and there is only one method: Carefully to study for any difference between those records shown and those not shown. There _will_ be some (tiny) difference.

Comment: When you remove what condition - the master/child links?

Comment: @June7 yes when master/child links are removed

Comment: Purpose of master/child links is to synchronize related records. Only related records are supposed to show. Why would you expect or desire otherwise?

Comment: @June7 THe problem i am facing is that related records are not shown. When i remove the condition, i can see related rows in child as rows are not filtered and i can scroll through the records.

Comment: I expect the issue is with data and/or form design. Since there is no code, this is an issue we cannot test and reproduce and therefore cannot advise specifics. Would have to review actual file.